# Can DirectX11 Dynamic Shader Linkage be used without Shader Reflections?

Tags: directx, shader, directx-11, linkage

I tried to implement dynamic shader linkage from what I saw in the DirectX11 SDK,but they are using the Effects11 framework and shader reflections.I'm trying to get a cleaner more low-level implementation.For instance - for constants buffer instead of using reflections,I just set a struct.I couldn't find anywhere a clean tutorial on how to implement the dynamic shader linkage in DirectX,everyone uses huge pieces of Effects11 code.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use dynamic shader linkage in directx11 without using shader reflection, however it means that you need to know the names of the classes and interfaces at compile time.

I have achieved this myself by using a combination of shader preprocessor macros that i use to declare all of my shader classes, and a common header file that I include in both my shader and my .cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for this problem too.
Check this out:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff471421(v=vs.85).aspx

Maybe this would help. :)